# Multiple Selection jquery error

Tags: jquery, angular, selection

I am using jquery into angular to multiple select value from dropdown but the problem is when I select and try to console the function add "1" as a first number before the selected array

This is the HTML page:

```
<select  class="ui fluid multiple selection dropdown" id="multi-select">
    <option *ngFor="let objectif of listObjectif" [value]="objectif.id_obj">{{objectif.des_obj}}
    </option>
</select>
```

This is my code into the controller:

```
this.selectedObjectif = <[any]>[];
this.selectedObjectif = $('select#multi-select').dropdown('get value');
```

When I try to call the function, this is what I get:

```
(2) ["1", Array(4)]
0:"1"
1:(4) ["1", "8", "3", "16"]
length:2
```

The problem is I don't want to get the first value "1", I just want to get the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ngModel and modelChange to get the selected value or object.

```js
export class mySelectClass {

selectedObjectif: any;

mySelectedValue() {
 console.log(selectedObjectif);
}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedObjectif" (ngModelChange)="mySelectedValue()">
  <option *ngFor="let objectif of listObjectif" 
   [ngValue]="objectif.id_obj">{{objectif.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: when i use ngModel i won't be able to see the first element of the list  that's why i worked with jquery

Comment: what do you mean by that please elaborate or update code of what you tried and also which jquery plugin are you using ?

Comment: what i am trying to say is : when i see the dropdown i don't see the first item of the dropdown and once i start the scroll the items start show up , and that's why i ve used jquery